# Retrieving values/members from sorted set with non-contiguous scores

Tags: redis

I have a list of scores. Using these, I need to extract values from a redis sorted set.

I know I can use `zrangebyscore` - but what if the scores in my provided list aren't contiguous? In that case, I can't rely on a `zrangebyscore min max` type command.

What's the most efficient way to retrieve these values from the sorted set in that case? It seems the best I can do is one-by-one retrieval here. Correct?

---

Here's an example (showing the sorted set as a list of tuples):

```
list_of_scores = [4, 1, 3] # these are to be retrieved

sorted_set = [(item_1, 1),
              (item_2, 2),
              (item_3, 3),
              (item_4, 4)]
```

Each tuple is a `member, score` pair.

---

UPDATE: here's a suggestion:

```
for score in scores:
    my_pipeline.zrangebyscore("my_sorted_set",score,score)
result = my_pipeline.execute()
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data, as well as the result set that you'd like to retrieve?

Comment: @Aaron: added some in the question. It's off the cuff; let me know if I malformed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of one-by-one retrieval is too much RTT. You can either use `PIPELINE` or wrap the process into a Lua script to make the one-by-one retrieval more efficient.

Also, it seems that you are using the `Sorted Set` as a `HASH`, e.g. score as hash key, while member name as hash value. So maybe a `HASH` is more suitable for your scenario.

Comment: I added some code to the tail-end of my question. Is that one of your suggestions? As a complete aside, know of any docs related to round-trip times I can read? I'm a beginner and would like to create some sensitivity to the subject.

Comment: You should check the client API you're using. With pipeline you can send all commands without waiting for the reply one-by-one, and get all replies in a single step. Check the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_delay_time) for details on `RTT`